# control vibrator motor speed with ultrasonic sensors

Tags: motor

First, thank you for taking the time to read my post.

I am attempting to use 3 ultrasonic sensors to control 3 DC vibrator motor using the PWM output of an Arduino. Fairly simple, I know, but I'm just a beginner. :)

Here's my code,

```
int trigpin_1 = 2;
int echopin_1 = 3;
int trigpin_2 = 4;
int echopin_2 = 5;
int trigpin_3 = 6;
int echopin_3 = 7;
int motor_1 = 8;
int motor_2 = 9;
int motor_3 = 10;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigpin_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echopin_1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigpin_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echopin_2, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigpin_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echopin_3, INPUT);
  pinMode(motor_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigpin_1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(trigpin_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(trigpin_3, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  digitalWrite(trigpin_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(trigpin_2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(trigpin_3, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echopin_1, HIGH); 
  duration = pulseIn(echopin_2, HIGH);
  duration = pulseIn(echopin_3, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) /29.1;
  if (distance > 200)
  {
    analogWrite(motor_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motor_2, 0);
    analogWrite(motor_3, 0);
  }
  else if(200 == distance > 160)
  {
    analogWrite(motor_1, 50);
    analogWrite(motor_2, 50);
    analogWrite(motor_3, 50);
  }
  else if(160 >= distance > 90)
  {
    analogWrite(motor_1, 100);
    analogWrite(motor_2, 100);
    analogWrite(motor_3, 100);
  }
  else if(90 >= distance > 60)
  {
    analogWrite(motor_1, 150);
    analogWrite(motor_2, 150);
    analogWrite(motor_3, 150);
  }
  else if(60 >= distance > 40)
  {
    analogWrite(motor_1, 200);
    analogWrite(motor_2, 200);
    analogWrite(motor_3, 200);
  }
  else if(40 >= distance)
  {
    analogWrite(motor_1, 255);
    analogWrite(motor_2, 255);
    analogWrite(motor_3, 255);
  }

  Serial.print (distance);
  Serial.println (" cm");
  delay(100);
}
```

[image: here the Connections]

[image]

but the problem is the DC motors it will be on all the time with 100% duty cycle. if anyone can help me will be thankful

Comment: The wiring diagram is very difficult to read. It would be better tor read if you redraw it with the builtin schematic editor.

Comment: Does this 'if(160 >= distance > 90)' actually work as intended in arduinoees? I don't believe it does in any flavor of C. You also have 3 lines of 'duration = ...' so you're just overwriting the 1st 2 with the last one.

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a bit wrong with your code I'm afraid.

Firstly the if statements.  If the values are kept in descending order then you can do this:

```
if (distance > 200)
{...}
else if (distance > 160)  // This point won't be reached unless the value is less than 200.
{...}
else if (distance > 100)
{...}
```

I think what you were trying to do was:

```
if (distance < 200 && distance > 160)
{...}
```

but its not necessary.

You are reading the pulse lengths into a single variable overwriting the previous values.  This means you are only reading sensor 3.  If you want to average the values then try this:

```
duration = pulseIn(echopin_1, HIGH); 
duration += pulseIn(echopin_2, HIGH); // take the result and add it to duration.
duration += pulseIn(echopin_3, HIGH);
duration /= 3;   // divide duration by three and assign the result to duration.
```

Also I'm not sure about the positioning of your sensors, its possible that they might interfere with each other.  In which case write a function to read from the sensor and store the results in an array.

i.e.
    const int sensorTriggerPins[] = {2, 4, 6};
    const int sensorEchoPins[] = {3, 5, 7};

```
long readSensor (const int& triggerPin, const int& eechoPin)
{
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  return pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); 
}

void setup()
{
   long duration[3]; // Define a three element array.
   for (int sensor = 0; sensor < 3; ++sensor)
   {
      duration[index] = readSensor(sensorTriggerPin[index], sensorEchoPin[index]);
   }
}
```

I don't know if this will fix all your problems, but it should help.
(It might have been better if you posted this in the Arduino forum)

Comment: PS - You could streamline you setup function if you use arrays for the pin assignments, and you can do the same wit you motors too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use GPIO outputs to drive motors directly.  You'll likely burn-out your Arduino with the schematic you've given.  At a minimum you'll want to use transistors (that can handle the motor current load) to switch the motors on/off.